# Fixed nav overlaps main content

Tags: fixed, nav, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS framework and when i use fixed nav bar i have an issue nav bar overlaps main content and page title (take a look at attached images)

[image]

although it looks good on small screen size:

[image]

```
    <header>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <nav>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile"
               class="button-collapse  hide-on-large-only"><i
                        class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <a class="page-title">Page Title</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav fixed">
                <li><a href="/admin/posts" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Posts</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/spam" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Spam</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/inbox" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Inbox</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
   </header>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Documentation has an answer here: [Fixed Navbar](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#navbar-fixed)

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

You have to wrap the `<nav...` with a `div.navbar-fixed`.

Comment: still same issue, you can try it in your browser

Comment: @AliSherafat You're right. But that works fine on their website! So, I tested it using the CSS they use: http://materializecss.com/css/ghpages-materialize.css
For my amazement, that fixes the problem. Apparently, their release is different than what they're using on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is very old now, I've run on the same issue and I realized the answer. Materialize documentation says: "You can adjust the height of this outer div to change how much offset is on your content." when explaining how to use fixed navbars.

So the trick is set manually the height for `div.navbar-fixed` and make it the same as the height of your navbar, so it will offset your content.

In my case, I have tabs below the navbar and those were overlaping the content, so I set `div.navbar-fixed`'s height as the same as my navbar height and tabs height combined.

```html
<div class="navbar-fixed" style="height: 104px">
    <nav class="nav-extended">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo left">MyApp</a>
            <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger right">
                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-content">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
                <li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test1">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#test2">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="#test3">Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Note I added inline style, but you can reference the class in your own css file and set the height there for code organization purposes.